# How to color different objects with fillStyle

Tags: javascript, object, canvas, colors

I'm not sure if that's the correct question. I'm not managing to set different colors to different objects.

As seen below they all become red,

```
function Body(x, y, w, h, color, mode){
...
this.color = color;
this.draw = function(){     
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
};

var hero = new Body(10, 50, 30, 40, "red", 1);
var page = new Body(500, 150, 5, 5, null, 0);
var poop = new Body(40, 50, 4, 4, null, 1);
var floor = new Body(30, 300, 600, 30, null, 0);
```

Even if I add `ctx.fillStyle = null;` after `ctx.fillStyle = this.color;`
And if I set the other objects to have to some specific color like this:

```
var hero = new Body(10, 50, 30, 40, "red", 1);
var page = new Body(500, 150, 5, 5, "blue", 0);
```

the code bugs and colors appear to be randomly given.

Comment: What if you do `fillStyle` _before_ `fillRect()`?

Comment: You know the `color` for the `page`, `poop` and `floor` is `null` right?

Comment: `null` is not a valid value for `fillStyle` property, hence the browser will ignore it i.e, it will stay to what it was. If you don't want to have an color, then don't call `fill()` (or `fillRect`), or, even if it sounds weird and is not a good idea for performance, you can also set it to an valid transparent value (`rgba(0,0,0,0)` might be the safest).

Comment: edit: oh yeah it did work! I did had `fillStyle` before `fillRect()` but forgot to edit the code here. However it wasn't working still but because I had null in the other objects, which I assumed it would set the color to be anything but the previously set color.. black is the default, that's what I was expecting from "null"

Comment: Thanks for the help, can't seem to be able to upvote your comments though :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fillStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle) sets the fill color for the shapes you draw *after* it. You can't modify what you've already drawn. Therefore change the order of the statements:

```js
ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
```

Comment: I had it like that but forgot to edit the question // However it was still not working, but because I had only one object as "red" the others null.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example:

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";
  
  var cvs, ctx;
  
  cvs = document.getElementById("cvs");
  ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
  ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
  ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 10, 10);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0000ff";
  ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 10, 10);
}());
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs"></canvas>
```